# Unable to display user input in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am new to Django and trying to display user input text. I tried multiple things but nothing has worked so far. Advice/help needed!
Here are my files:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=4000)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

views.py

```
from .models import Post
from django.core.exceptions import *

def index(request):
    return render('index.html')

def result(request):
    p = request.POST['message']
    return render_to_response('result.html', {'message': p}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Welcome to index page</div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Enter your name</p>
        <form action="/polls/results.html/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">{% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="message">
            <input type="submit" value="Send!">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

results.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Result page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Here is the result</div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Your name is: {{ message }}</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static        
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.result, name='results'),
 ]
```

Comment: the form action is wrong please add your urls file so i can help you

Comment: oh, yes.  url.py added.

Answer (score 0):

edit your form action to `{% url 'result' %}` so it will be like this

```
<form action="{% url 'result' %}" ....>
....
....
</form>
```

this will generate the URL, you where hardcoding the url and it was wrong too we don't add `.html` to it, by the way you can do this without two two templates (in the same url) : )